# Cannot generate JNLP dynamically from ADF (JSF) application

Tags: oracle-adf, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an application developed with Oracle ADF ( JSF ) that uses an applet to send PDFs directly to the printer without showing them to the user. 
Since modern browsers (such as the latest versions of Google Chrome) apparently no longer support applets I have developed a swing application java replacing the mentioned applet, this should be distributed using web start.

The printing application is already developed , compiled into a JAR and signed , a first test with a static JNLP was apparently successful . 
My problem is that the JAR must receive parameters sent from the website where it is invoked and I do not know how get this. I have seen some examples that extend the JnlpDownloadServlet servlet that is part of the examples of Java, but I could not make anyone of these examples work properly. 
I use JDeveloper as IDE.
I hope someone of you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **was** having the same problem.
Following this link from [oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/14064023#14064023) I was able to put it to work.
I only add to revise the jnlp tags and attributes when creating the file, like

```
String jnlpRoot = "<jnlp spec=\"1.0+\" codebase=\"" + codeBaseUrl + "\" version=\"0.1\">\n"; //href="PrintApplet.jnlp"
```

The href attribute was the one that was breaking the download functionality, it was expecting a file inside the application.

Hope this helps